# Display complex image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can one display a complex 2D array via a pseudo-complex colormap?

Comment: It looks like you've just re-asked this question so you can add an answer, why not answer the original question you've linked? Your question contains literally no new information and it's required that the reader goes and reads the original

Comment: OK, honestly I think this isn't a great way to ask a question, it would be good to [edit] this so it's self-contained. The value to future readers is for questions to be discoverable, you could describe the problem you're trying to solve so that the linked question is _extended reading_ rather than _required reading_.

Comment: So I'm not allowed to make a basic response. Alright then.

Comment: I didn't do anything on this question since my original comment

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to use hue for the angle and lightness for the amplitude is good. But I would use a perceptually uniform color map for the hue, instead of using the computed hue from HSL or similar non-perceptually-uniform color space. For example the isoluminant cyclic colormap "phase" from [cmocean:

```matlab
% Linearly map [-pi,pi] to [0,255]
out = round(((angle(x) / pi) + 1) * (255/2));
% Apply the color map
cm = cmocean('phase');
out = reshape(cm(out(:) + 1, :), [size(out),3]);
% Modulate lightness with amplitude
m = abs(x);
m = m / max(m(:));
% Display
image(out .* m)
```

[image: output of code above]

Invert the image if you prefer white for zero amplitude:

```matlab
image(1- ((1 - out) .* m));
```

[image: output of code above]

Of course, depending on your goal, it can also be useful to put the real component into one channel and the imaginary component into another:

```matlab
% Put real component into red, imaginary component into green and blue
out = cat(3, real(x), imag(x), imag(x));
% Min-max scaling, but putting 0 at 50% gray
out = out / (2 * max(max(out(:)), -min(out(:)))) + 0.5;
% Display
image(out)
```

[image: output of code above]

[You can download `cmocean` from here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/57773-cmocean-perceptually-uniform-colormaps).

Comment: Thanks. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/3026aea557c03ce00b2eb5060ab63c33) my latest progress, along discussion and easily-runnable code, feedback would be nice if you're interested. I also commented on your answer - TL;DR, not a fan, but still a nice and simpler alternative. Can discuss here also, but my first comment would've been too long.

Comment: It's funny, I thought superimposing re + im is exactly what my original cmap was doing, since it looks so messy... I've not thought about what it's doing at all until yesterday (wasn't priority). I didn't think there's a way to fully encode a complex 2D array with one image, with phase and amplitude, pretty cool that there is.

Comment: You've solved my black problem, this is exactly how I'd want it relative to red and blue, but the R and B themselves I've hardly noticed at first glance. And, if I have it right, there's also white? (if not, that loses 'spin') Too little of that one. If R and B could be more pronounced, and white wider, that'd be ideal for me, though not priority enough to start editing colormaps.

Comment: Despite citing your source, [cmap.C6](https://cmap-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/catalog/cyclic/colorcet%3Acet_c6/) looks [quite different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egP2y.png)... Also, I closely checked and find `abs(x)` to be an over-aggressive mapping on alpha - the image disappears before values drop below 10%.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I downloaded `colorcet.m` ages ago, maybe these color maps have changed since. I don’t know what you link to, here it is at the official ColorCET website: https://colorcet.com/gallery.html#cyclic — it indeed looks a bit different. //// We need to use an isoiluminant color map if we want to encode an independent quantity in the lightness, and C6 is the only cyclic one in my old colorcet function. To make it isoiluminant it needs to go all the way around the hues, which means we see all 3 primaries and all 3 secondaries. Cyclic maps with fewer colors cannot be isoiluminant.

Comment: It implements your site in Python. Re: isoluminant few colors, dunno, I think C4 against a dark foreground is excellent, just fails to capture spin: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCTKD.png). And I struggle to call C3 uniform, the black-blue are troublesome. After much toying, [brown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PXjd.png) and [light-grayish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv6Jp.png) seem to be best backgrounds. I've been trying to balance the visibility of the last blue strip on the wavelet top-right of the white blob, and visibility of the blob's boundary.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The examples you link, they all have a non-circular boundary. The colors changing lightness means that the lightness that encodes the amplitude gets distorted. I cannot tell those are Gaussian profiles. — Maybe it’s best to provide two separate plots, one for phase and one for amplitude.

Comment: I've somewhat glossed over [C1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWPhy.png)... it meets all non-optional requirements! Well, it advertises 4, but I see cyan as quite distinct from blue - dominant 5, total 6. Circular shape is well-seen, amplitude is handled by the ideal white, phase progression appears as linear (unless we're staring down the cyan), spin is identified as red-to-blue's direction, and zero is yellow. The zero is clearer on small wavelets with C3's white, but that's a minor point. -- Generally yes, I think best is viewing all three plots - mag, phase, and superimposed.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon In those plots, the blue and red bars look longer to me than the yellow and pink ones in between. Because the lightness changes from color to color.

Comment: Eh, think that's more a "looking closely" thing, at least for this image. I found [C6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHtvE.png) best for capturing variability and amplitude, but loses spin, and chaos if high freq. Also C1 tends to suffer blur depending on shape, unlike C6, and C3's blackness can get worse in some cases -- Decided I'll recommend between C1, 3, 4, and 6 for different uses.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Indeed it looks like what used to be C6 is now called C10. And it's not in the gallery at https://colorcet.com/gallery.html#cyclic . I agree this is not the most recognizable colors, but it's the best I've found that doesn't change the lightness. Any other color map you're compromising on how precisely you can read the amplitude, to be able to read the phase more precisely. From your `cmap` page, [cmocean:phase](https://cmap-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/catalog/cyclic/cmocean%3Aphase/) is also isoluminant, and more saturated. Did you try that one?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Updated the answer with cmocean's phase. I think it's a bit easier to read the phase off of it than ColorCET C10.